# Program not closing correctly c# and problems with forms

Tags: c#, winforms

[this is what of the errors I get when closing the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJhtf.png)

then I'm closing the program it's not fully closing and it's still active in the background how I fix it?

and plus then switching forms ex:

`this.Hide();
Form2 main = new Form2();
main.Show();`

and going back it's showing again the check for updates message box

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        if (!webClient.DownloadString("https://pastebin.com/raw/n77ayreS").Contains("1.6"))
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Looks like there is an available update, would you like to download it?", "Check For Updates", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://github.com/TomerGamerTV/Unreal-Cracking-Pack/releases");
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You are on the latest version!", "Check For Updates");
        }
```

this is my first time asking here so sorry if I did something wrong

Comment: search for flatTextBox3 in the project and see if other than main thread accessing

Comment: You could use Environment.Exit(0) to close your application and make sure every thread gets terminated

Comment: You are doing multithreaded access to the form, add a complete example to see what's happening.

Comment: When a background thread want to talk with the UI thread, it must use an appropriate mechanism to do so. Usually when you close a program, you want to first cancel background tasks and then wait until they are terminated before closing the main application.

**None of the code in your question is helpful to help us answer you**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Environment.Exit(0)` is fixed the program thx Paul Sütterlin